# How to show values in textboxes when combobox value select in c# windows application using layer architecture

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sqlite, combobox

I have a code to show combobox value in textboxes and code work fine for me but I convert my project into layer architecture (UI, BLL, DAL, Entity). I don't know c# very well and I'm learning the c#. My problem is that I want to change my code into layer architecture but I don't know how to do that, please help me. 
Here is the code.

```
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=combolist.db;Version=3;"))
            {
                string CommandText = "SELECT * FROM combo WHERE [Id]=@id";
                using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(CommandText, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = dr["Id"].ToString();
                        textBox2.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                        textBox3.Text = dr["LastName"].ToString();
                        textBox4.Text = dr["Age"].ToString();
                        textBox5.Text = dr["Address"].ToString();

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I would very much recommend not doing that in the `SqliteConnection`. Close connection, return the `dataTable` and _then_ manipulate

Comment: What exactly is your problem and what you want to do?

Comment: In your DAL, create a method that returns the DataTable from the query.  For example call it GetData().  Then in your form's code, assign values to the textbox as you have in your example after calling DAL.GetData() using the DataTable that's returned. As a general practice, the DAL should know nothing about the form and vice versa.